# Unable to export firebase data as JSON.

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question has been asked several times before but none of the solution is working.

I am trying to export firebase data as JSON using firebase console. I have tried all the solutions that are there on google and stackoverflow.

Is there any other way to solve this issue.

My JSON data is 500 MB. Sometimes it starts downloading data but then it stops and completes at 300 MB.

Comment: Please post the error which you are getting to figure out why **none of the solution is working**

Comment: There is no specific error.

If I try using curl error is that payload is too large. 

if I try using firebase export it says This site can’t be reached 

If I try using firebase export module it says that length is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase support helped me out so I decided to answer this here as well.

The issue I was encountering with the Realtime Database export via the Firebase Console was intended. The database size for my project was greater than 300 MB. There's a limit on the size of data that can be exported from the database which is 256 MB (an export is also equal to a read).

I tried some public modules which were not working as well.

The solution is to upgrade the firebase plan and backup your data which is then available as a G-zipped compressed file.

if you don't what to upgrade then you may use any public modules like this one https://github.com/n6g7/firebase-backup.

Thanks to firebase support.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a very bigger database, the export button maybe not works as you said, take a look into this library that i have created, i have developed it because my database have more than 600Mb and i need to backup using a service in some hours of day.

https://github.com/GeovRodri/firebase-realtime-database-backup